# Mapping GPL Platform Number to Microarray Name

Tags: r, bioconductor, geoquery, geo

I am trying to download a dataset from GEO using the GEOquery R package. Using this package, I can retrieve the GPL platform number(s) for the dataset, and I hope to use a CDF file from BrainArray on the dataset in order to undo any existing normalization performed, so that I can have multiple datasets that are normalized in a standard manner.

In order to do this, I need to know what the microarray platform name is. This information is usually provided on the website online (for example, [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE15245), you can see that next to GPL96, it says HG-U133A, which is the CDF I would use from BrainArray).

However, I am wondering if there is any way to parse this platform name using the GEOquery package in R itself rather than having to manually check for every dataset and compare it to the BrainArray website?

If it is not possible to do this in the GEOquery package, is there any online tool for mapping GPL to platform name? I found [this](https://gist.github.com/seandavi/bc6b1b82dc65c47510c7) online which has the mapping for a decent amount of GPL numbers, but not all of them, meaning it sometimes crashes. I was wondering if there is a foolproof way to do what I am trying to do.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edit:

I know I can access the highlighted portion in the first image below (the GPL platform number) through GEOquery. I'm wondering if I can access the name of the platform (highlighted in the second image). If not, my alternative option will probably be to scrape the web page to find this information, but if its possible to do so through GEOquery I'd rather do that.

[image]